# How to properly get jwt token from headers and use it with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, authorization

I created both frontend and backend in express.js with auth & authorization (jwt), now, jwt-token is properly set when I try to login as you can see from this picture below: (the auth-token key)

[image: headers]

But how do I get the headers and then use it so the user gets access to his/her data ?

This is how I have created the token in login process

```js
  const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, "SECRET");
  
  res.header("auth-token", token).send({status: "done", token: token});
```

This is a middleware for verifying

```js
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  
  //getting the token from headers to check if token is present or not
  const token = req.header("auth-token");
  if(!token) return res.status(401).send("Access Denied");
  
  try {
    const verified = jwt.verify(token, "SECRET");
    req.user = verified;
    next();
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send("Token is Invalid")
  }
}
```

This is a part of my server.js file

```js
app.user(express.json());

app.use("/user", verifyJWT);

app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/frontend/userDetails.html")
});
```

Now every time I login and visit the /user route it shows "Access Denied" what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The server sending a header back to the browser doesn't mean the browser needs to start including that header in every request.

Whenever your client sends a request to your server, it has to **manually** *(using a wrapper or library aside)* add the `auth-token` header to the request. If you want the browser to automatically add the header for each request, you'd want to use cookies instead.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it manually? I searched for it but they were all till where i have done. Sorry if its a beginner level doubt

Comment: I don't know what library you use on the frontend for HTTP requests. Your question says Express.js but as far as I know, that's a (server-side only) HTTP **server**, not client.

Comment: I am using vanilla JavaScript for frontend and express.js for backend

Comment: Then you'll probably use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) _(not vanilla, but very common)_, which both supports headers. Pretty much any client-side library that supports performing HTTP requests supports adding headers. Check their documentation.

Comment: Yeah i know that, I know `fetch` and I am using it in this project. My doubt is first the request will be send to server right then server decides to give this user access or not depending on his/her login status (with jwt), so how can I pass the token from client to server ? Did you understand ?

Comment: Look it up. Basically the user authenticates and get the token (either the server sent it in a header or in the body, doesn't matter). Then whenever the user performs a request that needs authentication, include the token in the headers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235516/discussion-between-viraj-d-and-kelvin-schoofs).